# Развертывание asp.net MVC приложения на Apache с помощью ISPManager 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, apache2, ispmanager

Привет!
Пытаюсь развернуть asp.net mvc приложение на Apache. Для этого:

1) Собираю приложение из исходников в Visual Studio 2013 с помощью команды Publish (метод: File System)

2) Полученные файлы загружаю на сервер хостинг-провайдера (настройка сайта у провайдера осуществляется через ISPManager5 панель)

3) Если в настройках домена указать запуск с конкретного cshtm-файла, то отображается только html-код страницы. 
Позвольте поясню. Например, указываю стартовой страницу приложения List.cshtml (в файле роутинга она и является стартовой)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат - html код страницы:

Предполагаю, что ошибка как раз в указании конкретного файла. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобными проблемами? Буду благодарен за подсказку о направлении дальнейшей работы.

Comment: А вы уверены, что хостинг вообще поддерживает ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 2):

В support провайдера пояснили, что скорее всего собрать asp на их платформе не удастся. Полагаю, вопрос закрыт. Спасибо